# Downloading Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I started downloading Ubuntu last night.  It has stopped downloading. I am installing it along side windows.  How do I get it to continue to download?  It is locked-up.

Comment: How are you downloading?

Answer (score 2):

Download through torrent so you can pause and resume download anytime you want.

> BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer download network that sometimes enables
>   higher download speeds and more reliable downloads of large files. You
>   will need to install a BitTorrent client on your computer in order to
>   enable this download method.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Use a torrent client and the alternative downloads section that way you can resume progress

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

utorrent works well on windows - http://www.utorrent.com/